# My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile Method stuck on a file

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using VB 2010 and I'm using My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile Method to download all the files listed in a listbox, around 1000 files.

After a couple of files get downloaded successfully, the downloading stuck on next file, it may be downloaded to any percentage. but t repeats after downloading couple of file.
I've enabled the UI and set DoNothing when Cancelled. So I need to cancel to jump to next file..
Whats the solution?

Here is the code

```
    Private Sub btnDLFile2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDLFile2.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To lstReapedLinks.Items.Count - 1


        Dim targetFile As String = lstReapedLinks.Items(i).ToString
        Dim destFile As String = "e:\dls\files\" & i & ".jpg"

        lblDLFile.Text = "Downloading " & targetFile

        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(targetFile, destFile, "", "", True, 60000, True, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us some code, in particular the method you're using to do the download.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Are you downloading these files from a web server?

If so try using `WebClient.DownloadFile` - you'll need to wrap it in `try{...}catch{...}` in case of failure.

```
Import System.Net

Dim fileReader As New WebClient()
dim fileAddress = "http://www.where-ever.com/TheFileYouWant.jpg"
fileReader.DownloadFile(fileAddress, "c:\YourSaveLocation\" + your-new-filename)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(targetFile, destFile, "", "", True, 60000, True, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
```

[result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvY55.png)

PS I tried to do everything right, if it didn't work out - I'm so sorry :)